# Eslint react/no-typos rule throw an error when declare a property as style

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint, react-proptypes

I have a problem with an eslint in react native application. I'm declaring styles property for my component. It looks like:

```
Component.propTypes = {
   styles: ViewPropTypes.style,
   textStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
}
Component.defaultProps = {
   styles: null,
   textStyle: null,
}
```

and I'm getting the following eslint errors:

```
295:25  error  Typo in declared prop type: style         react/no-typos
296:20  error  Typo in declared prop type: propTypes     react/no-typos
296:30  error  Typo in prop type chain qualifier: style  react/no-typos
```

I have noticed that I'm getting them with es6 syntax. When I use an es7 everything is fine.
May you tell me what I do wrong?

My versions of libraries are:

```
"prop-types": "15.6.1",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.0",

"eslint": "^4.11.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.41.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.9.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
```

Thanks and sorry for my English skill.

Comment: Can you try using eslint-plugin-react@7.10.0 ?
I think they fixed some bugs related to `no-typos` rule.

Comment: Thanks, it works. You can write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using eslint-plugin-react@7.10.0? I think they fixed some bugs related to no-typos rule.

Answer (score 4):

Use `camelCase` notation like `.propTypes` , **not** `.PropTypes`.